# Is there a "One To Many" connection in Linux File socket?

Tags: linux, sockets, connection

1) I wonder if there is a "One to Many" connection in Linux file socket.
2) And, also Is there a limit of Connection in Linux file socket?

These days, I'm studying Linux socket system.
And I knew that There is a One to Many connection in Linux socket by IP.
But I'm curious about that there is also One to Many Connection in Linux File socket, not IP.

And If there is, I also wonder that There is a limit number of Connection in Linux file socket. For example In a one-to-many relationship, the number of majority can't exceed 100, etc.

Please Help me.